How to upgrade docker 24.0.5 to 27.3.1 in Ubuntu Jammy 22.04?
I have a Ubuntu Jammy server 22.04 LTS with the following installed:
apt-offline_1.8.4-1_all.deb
Docker-ce: 24.0.5 (offline installer: docker-ce_24.0.5-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb)
Docker-ce-cli: 24.0.5 (offline instaler: docker-ce-cli_24.0.5-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb)
containerd: 1.6.9 (offline installer: containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb)
I saw there's a number of newer files available for upgrade:
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/
docker-ce_27.3.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb
docker-ce-cli_27.3.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb
containerd.io_1.7.23-1_amd64.deb

Can I upgrade my existing docker-ce / docker-ce-cli / containerd to the latest version directly?

Do I need to uninstall the older version? I have a postgres db container, will I lose all my data if I uninstall the containerd?

Is there any latest apt-offline file for Jammy?

Also, I saw the following files available as well:


docker-buildx-plugin_0.17.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb
docker-ce-rootless-extras_27.3.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb
docker-compose-plugin_2.6.0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
docker-scan-plugin_0.23.0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
Are these files necessary for my Ubuntu server? Btw, due to the enclosed laboratory environment, there's no internet available for the server.

Do I need to upgrade Jammy to Noble in order to upgrade the docker (v 27.3.1) & containerd (1.7.23)?

Best Regards,

This question is similar to: How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
